# Geolocation tracking

Tags: windows-phone-7

Im building an app to track my cycling tours.
I want to track my geographical movements. From that I want to calculate max speed, average speed and route.
What is the best practice? Should I save his geolocation every 5 seconds to isolated storage or is there a more performance optimized method? I dont know if saving to isolated storage is battery intensive and maybe there's some sort of session object which I can save each minute so that its less battery intensive.
Ofcourse the shorter the timeperiod in which I save users' location the more accurate I am, but what is considered best practice (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolated Storage is generally used to store data that needs to remain after the app closes. So while you'll eventually save to Isolated Storage (assuming you plan on saving the data), you don't have to do it every time you get a new result.

How often you get the data is up to you, but obviously the more often you get it, the more battery intensive the app will be. You could decide that you want to get it every `X` meters. You can adjust the [MovementThreshold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to suit your app. Every time the user has travelled the `MovementThreshold's` value, the [PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.positionchanged%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event will fire.

As for saving, you could just get the value every interval and store it in a `List`. Then, when the user finishes, you can write that list to Isolated Storage. If you find that the list starts to take too much memory, you can then write that to the Isolated Storage, clear the list and start again.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the answer and detail level I needed! :)